# Has anyone ever had Registry.dispatch just randomly stop dispatching events?

Tags: websocket, registry, elixir, dispatch

I have an app that consumes events from a websocket feed. It calls `Registry.dispatch/3` to send messages to subscribed genservers, which then in turn prints them to console. The pipelining is handled by genstage. A producer sits on the socket and generates events with receive calls. The consumer then manages a state and dispatches events to processes in a registry if the state is affected in a specific way. The processes subscribed to the registry would log the event when they receive a message via `handle_info/2`.

After running the app for ~ 20 minutes, the events stop getting logged to the console without anything happening. In the console, I looked at the registry process and saw the processes had unsubscribed as there were no associated registries with that key, but no errors were thrown and everything happened silently. I also was still getting events so the genstage consumer was still consuming events, and its breaking at the registry dispatching point. I can verify the websocket connection did not close, and events were still being read.

This is a replicable issue. The events stop being printed after about the same delay on each run, which is perplexing. That would make me think there's a leak of some sort somewhere, but the load graphs on the observer seem to indicate that all is fine.

Disclaimer: I am a total beginner at Elixir and I could just be missing something obvious and trivial but outside my knowledge scope.

Answer (score 0):

> The pipelining is handled by `GenStage`.

This mostly looks like a deadlock in `GenStage` handling demand. Once the *consumers* send the demand, and the *producer* returns an empty list of events from `handle_demand`, the consumers *do stop sending demand*.

This is [done on purpose](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/issues/80#issuecomment-246590264) and it’s a duty of the *producer* to collect the requested demand *and serve* it afterwards.

Comment: Hey. So the GenStage consumer does two things actually—it writes to an ets table, and it dispatches events through Registry.dispatch. I can see that the ets table is still being written to, but the processes subscribed to the Registry are not receiving dispatch events. That's why I don't think it's a GenStage issue.